# Check if <form> text element is null

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to do an error check in Javascript which would pop up if a form-text element is empty.

```
var itemPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tPrice").value);

if(itemPrice < 0 || itemPrice == null)
{
  alert("Please enter a valid price");
  return false;
}
```

I have tried `itemPrice == "null"`and `itemPrice === "null"`.

Any insight would be great, thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed my if statement to this and it worked perfectly!

if(itemPrice < 0 || document.getElementById("tPrice").value==='')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the value is empty, just write `getElementById("tPrice").value===''` without parseFloat.

```
var itemPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tPrice").value);

if(getElementById("tPrice").value==='' || itemPrice < 0)
{
  alert("Please enter a valid price");
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the results you are looking for

```
if (typeof itemPrice == "undefined" || itemPrice <= 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function to tell if the function is not a number, which not only works for blank / empty values but also for any random text.

*In the example below stackoverflow does not allow `alert` statements to be run, so I changed it to display the results inline.*

```js
function validateField() {
    var itemPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tPrice").value),
        result = document.getElementById("result");
    
    if(isNaN(itemPrice) || itemPrice < 0) {
        result.innerHTML = '<span style="background:red;color:#fff">Please enter a valid price</span>';
        return false;
    }
    result.innerHTML = '<span style="background:green;color:#fff">Price is valid</span>';
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tPrice" />
<button onclick="validateField();">Validate Field</button>
Result:<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the itemPrice have to be a number > 0 try this:

```
var itemPrice = document.getElementById("tPrice").value;

if(!(itemPrice > 0)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid price");
    return false;
}
```